# How can I keep a rolling average of the latest 10 scores for 30 different players?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to create a spreadsheet to keep track of scores for a group of golfers (about 30) who don't all play the same number of rounds.

The rolling average should keep track of only the last 10 scores.  I would welcome a way to create a table - where the latest score could be entered and a new average reflected from the most recent 10 scores.

Comment: I believe in Excel it is doable, in SQL it would be a piece of cake.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a helper column and a pivot table.

If all your score data is in one table with fields for `Player Name`, `Date/Time`, and `Score`, you can add a fourth field `MostRecentRank` which will display the rank of the date for each record, specific to that player. If `Player Name` is in column `A` and `Date/Time` is in column `B`, you can enter the following in `D2` and fill down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$1000=A2),--($B$2:$B$1000>B2))+1
```

Next, create a pivot table from your data. Add `Player Name` to Rows and Average of `Score` to Values. Add `MostRecentRank` to the Report Filter.  Then, you can adjust the filter to consider only values 1 through 10.

You will have to refresh your pivot table as you add more data.

Example with 3 players and looking at 4 most recent scores:

**Setting up pivot table**
[image]

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is quite vague I will offer a simple although manual solution: you could just have 30 worksheets (one per golfer).

List the scores going down the spread sheet in one column, for example starting in A1 and down for an infinite amount of rows (or until Excel says no).

In cell B1 you have a simple formula which adds the last 10 results together and converts to %.

You add the new score to the bottom of Col A when a new result is in. You also update B1 cell reference.

You could even then create another work sheet and just reference B1 of each worksheet to compare scores.

Or, you could use 1 worksheet and use different columns for different golfers but maybe the first row for the average, underneath for all the results per round.

Either way, with my suggestion, you will have to probably do some house keeping otherwise your lists will become very long and messy.